# Essential Supremum of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability

$X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are iid sequence of random variables with $a_1:=esssup$ $X$ and $a_2=essinf$ $X$.

I am trying to show,

1. $\mathbb{P}(\text{lim sup } X_n = a_1)$
2. $\mathbb{P}(\text{lim inf } X_n = a_2)$

To prove the first part, I proceed as follows:

Fix $\epsilon>0$. $\mathbb{P}(\text{lim sup }\left[ |X_n - a_1|>\epsilon\right])=\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\cup_{n\ge N}\left[ |X_n - a_1|>\epsilon\right]\right)$

$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge N}{P}\left(\left[ |X_n - a_1|>\epsilon\right]\right)$

$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge N}\left({P}\left[ X_n>a_1+\epsilon\right]+{P}\left[ X_n<a_1-\epsilon\right]\right)$

The first term inside the summation is 0 since $a_1$ is the essential supremum and the second term is $<1$ and this is where I am stuck. I am trying to use the Borel Cantelli Lemma and somehow I will have to show that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge N}{P}\left[ X_n<a_1-\epsilon\right]<\infty$. Any hints on how I should proceed or if this approach does not make sense? I am aware that $P(X_n<a)<1$ for all $n$ and any $a<a_1$ but I believe I need to use this fact somehow.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb P(\limsup_n X_n>a_1)=0$ is easy, because $\Bbb P(X_n>a_1)=0$ for each $n$.

So you need to show that $\Bbb P(\limsup_n X_n\le b)=0$ for each $b\in(-\infty,a_1)$. Equivalently, $\Bbb P(\limsup_n X_n>b)=1$. Here is where Borel-Cantelli might come in handy, because $\{\limsup_n X_n>b\}=\limsup_n\{X_n>b\}$.

Comment: Thanks John. I see your point and I proceed as follows. Take b=a_1-epsilon. Then finally I still need to show that sum over n>=N, P(X_n>a_1-epsilon) is not finite which is same as showing sum over n>=N, P(X_n<a_1-epsilon) is finite. This is the place where I am stuck. I know that P(X_n<a)<1 for any a<a_1 but I guess I need to use it somehow.

Comment: By complements, $\Bbb P(X_n>b)>0$ for $b<a_1$. Don't forget your $X_n$s are iid.

Comment: Ah, they are indeed iid. Ok so each term is positive and they take the same value. Great thanks a lot.